# Inner Join on Empty Values

Tags: sql-server

```
TableName:Emp
EmpId   EmpName EmpAddressId
1       Ram          100
2       Ravi            
3       Raj          102
4       Kiran        
5       Bujji        101


TableName:Address
AddressId   Address
101             India
102             Uk
103             US


select E.*,A.Address from EMP E inner join Address A 
on E.EmpId=2 and E.EmpAddressId='' or E.EmpAddressId=A.AddressId


out put should display as for EmpId:2
------------------------------
EmpId  EmpName EmpAddressId  Address
 2       Ravi      

for EmpId:3
------------
EmpId  EmpName EmpAddressId  Address
 3       Raj     102           Uk
```

For employee 2  there is no EmpAddressId but here requirement is need to display as null values or empty values.
can any one help this.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `INNER JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN` (or `LEFT OUTER JOIN`). That will result in `NULL` for all columns from `Address` table if there's no match. Also, you can replace your join condition with a simpler version:

```
select E.EmpId, E.EmpName, E.EmpAddressId, A.Address
from EMP E left join Address A 
on E.EmpAddressId=A.AddressId
where E.EmpId=2
```

More on outer joins on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Here I need individual employees not for all employees. I mean  EmpId as  input parameter.

Comment: Ah ok, I added it back.

Answer (score 1):

**Inner join** will yield to null if any of the joining table is null.. If all the table has value then use inner join else go for left join. It ensures that atleast you will get let joined table values.

For this ,you use **left join**

```
select e.EmpId, e.EmpName, e.EmpAddressId, a.Address

from EMP e left join Address a 

on e.EmpAddressId=a.AddressId

where e.EmpId=2
```